# Get reference to certain cell in UIcollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get a reference to the first cell in collection view in order to move it (for some effect) .

first, can you move a certain cell that is inside the collection ?

second,how would i check if its on visible rect right now? (cells are reusable) .

**ERROR:** when i do this, i am also getting an error when i set the index path to *non zero*

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:4];//E
    CGRect cellRect = cell.frame;
    NSLog(@"%f",cellRect.origin.y);



}
```

"implicit conversion of int is disallowed in ARC ".

When its set to 0 , i always get position of 0, even when the cell is offscreen.

I guess i am missing the right way to get the first cell ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create an instance of an NSIndexPath to use `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

**Example**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:4 inSection:0];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect cellRect = cell.frame;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some example ?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 version code:** based on Luca Bartoletti answer

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0)
    var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    var cellRect = cell.frame
}
```